# Are letter/number combinations in HTML lists possible?

Tags: html, html-lists

Quite simply, I want an ordered list to work like this:

```
 1. Foo
 2. Bar
3a. Baz
3b. Qux
 4. Etc...
```

Is there any way to easily do something along these lines in HTML?

Comment: You can try using a nested list. (an `<ol>` inside of the `<li>`). Won't give that exact result though.

Comment: @Truth I have considered that, but that makes the formatting look bad. I'd really like to be able to do something like this without compromising the compact and consistent format.

Comment: The compact and consistant format is not a problem, you just fiddle with the margins and they'll be on the same line. You won't get 3a or 4b though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the following mark-up:

```
<ol>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>
        <ol>
           <li>bar</li>
           <li>baz</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Something else...</li>
</ol>​
```

The following CSS *almost* works:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: topLevel;
}

li {
    counter-increment: topLevel;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

li::before {
    content: counter(topLevel) '. ';
    margin-right: 0.3em;
}

ol ol {
    counter-reset: secondLevel;
}

ol ol li {
    counter-increment: secondLevel;
}

ol ol li::before {
    content: counter(topLevel) counter(secondLevel, lower-alpha) '. ';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5zLpg/).

The only problem with this, so far, is that it contains the `topLevel` count against both the inner `li` elements (as you wanted), but also against the outer `li` (that contains those inner elements), so...not quite there, yet.

And the above problem resolved! ...in those browsers that support the CSS `:not()` selector:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: topLevel;
}

li {
    counter-increment: topLevel;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

li:not(.hasChild)::before {
    content: counter(topLevel) '. ';
    margin-right: 0.3em;
}

ol ol {
    counter-reset: secondLevel;
}

ol ol li {
    counter-increment: secondLevel;
}

ol ol li::before,
ol li.hasChild ol li::before {
    content: counter(topLevel) counter(secondLevel, lower-alpha) '. ';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5zLpg/2/).

I forgot (originally) to note that for this to work (because CSS doesn't have a parent selector ([as yet](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject)) I had to add a specific class to those `li` elements with child `ol` elements in order to appropriately hide the duplication of the number. In this case I chose the class-name `.hasChild` (as can be seen in the Fiddle).

Incidentally, a small change to the `li:not(.hasChild)::before` rules, allows for the right-aligned text:

```
li:not(.hasChild)::before {
    content: counter(topLevel) '. ';
    width: 2em;
    margin-right: 0.3em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5zLpg/4/).

Comment: Nice work with the letter number mix.  I couldn't seem to get that one working.  The only `:not` supporting browsers issue is an easy fix.  Just apply it to all then override the rule for those that have the class  http://jsfiddle.net/5zLpg/3/

Comment: Thanks! =) (for the compliment and the fix!)

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. Crazily complicated, but awesome all the same. Still, I'd assume browser support is limited... any idea on what would appear in a non-compliant browser?

Comment: I knew a counter was able to achieve it, didn't exactly know how. +1.

Comment: @Jake: I don't have one with which I can test, unfortunately. Though, basically, it's an IE problem (and the (much) older versions of Webkit, Gecko, etc.).

Comment: @DavidThomas Well, I'm willing to drop IE support for this particular project. Great stuff!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't meet your requirements fully and requires some (annoying) changes to your html, but I think it's about as close as you'll get.

http://jsfiddle.net/qGCUk/30/

```
<ol>
    <li>one</li>
    <li class="has_children">
        <ol>
           <li>two.one</li>
           <li>two.two</li>
           <li>two.three</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

---

```
ol,li{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;    
}
ol { counter-reset: item }
li { display: block; padding-left: 0 }
li:before { 
    content: counters(item, ".") " "; 
    counter-increment: item 
}
LI.has_children:before { 
    content: " "; 
    counter-increment: item 
}
```

This is only numbers, as I don't think you can mix numbers and letters.  And since there is no selector to select and `li` which contains and `ol`, you have to add a class to any `li` which has a child `ol`.